# missing values from sameperiodlastyear in powerpivot

Tags: dax, powerpivot

Greeting. I am new to DAX.

This is what I got...

[img][https://i.ibb.co/8YsMVpV/A91-B5-FF1-569-B-4-B99-B3-C7-A3510-AE0-A798.jpg[/img]](https://i.ibb.co/8YsMVpV/A91-B5-FF1-569-B-4-B99-B3-C7-A3510-AE0-A798.jpg%5B/img%5D)

This is what I want...

[img][https://i.ibb.co/TMqP1cW/B264458-C-BA48-4204-885-F-30-D41-DBB7754.jpg[/img]](https://i.ibb.co/TMqP1cW/B264458-C-BA48-4204-885-F-30-D41-DBB7754.jpg%5B/img%5D)

The problem I have now is missing "Other-COT" sales from MTD LY. Everything is good (including the shop total) except "Other-COT" is not showing in my pivot table.

I guess the reason is MTD data has no Other-COT sales for shop ABC and MTD LY is bounded by MTD's season filter.

Highly appreciate if someone could help me or could give me a clue.

Below are my formulas,

Sales Net = sum(SALES[NetSales])

Sales Net MTD = CALCULATE([Sales Net],DATESMTD('Calendar'[Date]))

Sales Net MTD LY = CALCULATE([Sales Net MTD],SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]),FILTER(all(SALES),SALES[Date]>=STARTOFMONTH('Calendar'[Date])&&SALES[Date]<=DATEADD(STARTOFMONTH(SALES[Date]),DAY(MAX(SALES[Date]))-1,DAY)),KEEPFILTERS(Season_Master),KEEPFILTERS(Shop_Master))

And I have 2 slicers selecting Year and Month.

Million Thanks
James
[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcviU.png)